# Can I convert mp4 files to HLS format with Nginx?

Tags: nginx, mp4, http-live-streaming, rtmp

There is a module in nginx: ngx_http_hls_module

But I do not know how to use it and how to upload it to the server.

It is available in a dynamic module as follows: https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module

But it's pretty complicated. I don't know how to use this.

Can I use this in HLS format by adding .m3u8 at the end of .mp4 videos?

In terms of bandwidth, mp4 can be very costly. So I want to present the video files in HLS Format.

Comment: HLS would not be any cheaper to deliver.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your answer.

So, converting from .mp4 to .m3u8 will not help me.

Then I don't have to deal with it, thank you very much.